# How to get a line-numbered stack trace for a memory leak on Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, ada

I've managed to get the Xcode `leaks` tool to report leaks in my command-line GCC Ada program (by adding `delay 11.0;` at the end to let `leaks` make its checks) and then

```
$ export MallocStackLogging=1
$ (./foobar &)  && leaks foobar
```

which leads to (excerpted)

```
Process 52027: 18 nodes malloced for 2053 KB
Process 52027: 2 leaks for 32 total leaked bytes.
Leak: 0x1002000c0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x100175000 string '*'
        Call stack: [thread 0x7fff70bbcca0]: | start | main | _ada_foobar | __gnat_malloc | malloc | malloc_zone_malloc 
Leak: 0x1002000d0  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x100175000 string 'T'
        Call stack: [thread 0x7fff70bbcca0]: | start | main | _ada_foobar | __gnat_malloc | malloc | malloc_zone_malloc
```

which is a great deal better than nothing, but would be considerably improved with line numbers.

Are there any build options I should have used? Would it work better if the Ada compiler (FSF GCC 4.6.0, not from Apple) was integrated with Xcode?

This is an x86_64 build on 10.6.7, Xcode 3.2.6. Using -g makes no difference.

In the call stack, `main` is the `main()` generated by `gnatmake`, `_ada_foobar` is the Ada program in which the leak actually occurs. The other frames are from the run time system.

Comment: Any help from `/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools/Thread Viewer.app`?

Comment: I don't see Thread Viewer anywhere (nor does Spotlight). Is it an optional add-on?

Comment: It's included in Xcode 3.1.4', but it may have been dropped from 3.2.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) 3.7.0 is available for Mac OS X; my code test was

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Leaker is
   type P is access Integer;
   procedure Inner is
      V : P;
   begin
      Put_Line ("allocating for 42");
      V := new Integer'(42);
      Put_Line ("allocating for 0");
      V := new Integer'(0);
      Put_Line ("done.");
   end Inner;
begin
   Inner;
end Leaker;
```

and I ran with

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --dsymutil=yes ./leaker
```

to get a report including

```
8 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 9
   at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
   by 0x100010CC7: __gnat_malloc (s-memory.adb:92)
   by 0x100001C7D: _ada_leaker (leaker.adb:14)
   by 0x100001BAA: main (b~leaker.adb:191)
```

`leaker.adb:14` is the call to `Inner`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the chief issue here is exactly which compiler you have. The versions of Gnat you get from ACT come with a link libraray addr2line.lib that can be used to produce symbolic tracebacks at runtime.

The versions of Gnat you get from the FSF distributions don't have that library. However, there is still the addr2line program that comes with Gnu's "binutils". You do have that available for you on your Mac setup, right?

If you feed your hex addresses into that program, it should report the symbolic information you want. You may have to reformat your `leaks` output a bit for addr2line to accept it.

Comment: Unfortunately the Mac version of GNAT GPL doesn't come with `libaddr2line.a` or `addr2line`; instead of `addr2line` you use `atos` (I see that binutils-2.21 does in fact build `addr2line`, but it doesn't seem to work very well). And, in any case, the trouble with the call stacks I quote is that the only hex value they contain is the thread ID!

Comment: I should add, when `leaks` reports `Leak: 0x1002000c0  size=16` ... it's reporting the address of the allocated memory, not the code that allocates it.

Answer (score 1):

Although less dispositive than `valgrind`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8144435/230513), it's possible to `Spawn` an instance of `leaks` without `delay` as shown below. `Spawn` blocks, allowing `leaks` to conclude before proceeding. In the best case, it's a quick way to verify that no leaks were found; if not, paired calls can narrow the search for offending code.

Code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.OS_Lib; use GNAT.OS_Lib;
procedure Leaker is
   type P is access Integer;
   procedure Inner is
      V : P;
   begin
      Put_Line ("allocating for 42");
      V := new Integer'(42);
      Put_Line ("allocating for 0");
      V := new Integer'(0);
      Put_Line ("done.");
   end Inner;
   Result    : Integer;
   Command   : constant String        := "/usr/bin/leaks";
   Arguments : constant Argument_List :=
     (1 => new String'("-quiet"), 2 => new String'("leaker"));
begin
   Result := Spawn (Command, Arguments);
   Inner;
   Result := Spawn (Command, Arguments);
end Leaker;
```

Console:

```
leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 46711: 156 nodes malloced for 8 KB
Process 46711: 0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.

allocating for 42
allocating for 0
done.
leaks Report Version: 4.0
Process 46711: 158 nodes malloced for 8 KB
Process 46711: 2 leaks for 32 total leaked bytes.

    2 (32 bytes) << TOTAL >>
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7f8f83504080 [16]  length: 1  "*"
      1 (16 bytes) ROOT LEAK: 0x7f8f83504090 [16]
```