# How to calculate the true symbol address in a binary for use with atos?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, llvm, atoi

I've been trying to figure out a way on how to calculate the exact symbol addresses from stack adresses I get from the crash reports. I've found the following formula: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464678/920407

And tried using a tool I found that calculates the address for me: https://github.com/nob1984/natos

But allas neither of these methods worked, though the error margin was relatively small - about 3-4 lines before the actual line that the error occurred in.

I deliberately forced the app to crash with overshooting an NSArray object bounds. This is my result:

crash report:

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x36bf688f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3300d259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36b4e23d -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 165
3   SomeApp                         0x0013cea3 -[DashboardTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (DashboardTableViewController.m:970)
4   UIKit                           0x34e7993d -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 945
5   UIKit                           0x34ef3627 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 159
6   Foundation                      0x32829933 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 415
7   CoreFoundation                  0x36bcaa33 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 15
8   CoreFoundation                  0x36bca699 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 365
9   CoreFoundation                  0x36bc926f __CFRunLoopRun + 1207
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36b4c4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36b4c36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
12  GraphicsServices                0x34d13439 GSEventRunModal + 137
13  UIKit                           0x34df5cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
14  SomeApp                         0x00146587 main (main.m:17)
15  SomeApp                         0x00102008 start + 40
```

natos output:

```
Main Stack Address == 0x146587
Target Stack Address == 0x13cea3
Slide == 0x1000
Main Symbol Address == 0x4751c
Load Address == 0x10006b
Target Symbol Address == 0x3de38


dwarfdump output:
(null)


atos output:
-[DashboardTableViewController tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:] (in SomeApp) (DashboardTableViewController.m:966)
```

As the Apple Crash report states the code line is actually in 970 and not 966. I wonder what's causing this error and what should one use to calculate the address correctly.

Comment: Can you use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075703/how-to-get-a-line-numbered-stack-trace-for-a-memory-leak-on-mac-os-x ? As a side note, GCC always seem to be a line off when I'm using addr2line....

Comment: are you solve your problem

Comment: Haven't been looking for one. I just used PLCrashReporter to solve my issue. (https://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/)